# Want an existing report to be in a different menu area

Tags: overrides

I am trying to get the report here "admin/report_sales/sales" to be duplicated under my custom menu area.  How should I do this as simply as possible?  Should I create a menu item, then use a redirect? Do I actually have to use a controller to redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a menu item to your menu with the same url. Here is an example with a piece of menu from adminhtml.xml of a custom module:

```
<menu>
    <main_menu_code translate="title"><!-- this is the top level menu -->
        <title>Main menu title</title>
        <sort_order>80</sort_order>
        <children>
            <report translate="title"><!-- this is the menu item for the sales report -->
                <title>Sales report</title>
                <action>adminhtml/report_sales/sales</action>
                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
            </report>
     </children>
    </main_menu_code>
</menu>
```

[EDIT]
To make your new menu selected try adding this to one of your admin layout files

```
<adminhtml_report_sales_sales>
    <reference name="menu">
        <action method="setActive">
        <menupath>main_menu_code/report</menupath><!-- replace values with your own menu tags -->
        </action>
     </reference>
</adminhtml_report_sales_sales>
```

Comment: when I try that I get 404

Comment: nevermind fixed that

Comment: Is there any way I can get the menu highlighting to look like it's still in my menu?

Comment: I updated the answer because it would look ugly in a comment.